# Inserting BLOB (xml ) values in to Oracle DB

Tags: xml, oracle

I am using Oracle 11g, I have to Insert the BLOB values which are in xml form in single sql query into database, How can I can I Achive this.

Below query I am trying out:

```
insert into CONNECTION_ACCOUNTS (SERVICE_SPECIFIC_DATA_V) values 
( xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<connection-specific>
  <connection value="0">
    <chargingGroupDetails>
      <groupInfo discountPercentage="10000000" classType="1" groupId="1001"/>
    </chargingGroupDetails>
  </connection>
</connection-specific') )
where account_id_n=1462;
```

But for some reason this is not working? first of all is it possible to do like this?

some reason it is not working.. Can somebody help me.. How Can I do this ?

Comment: the single quotes near UTF8, add two more single quotes - ''UTF8''

Comment: tried it.. still the same problem

Comment: Almost forgot: you cannot insert with where clause.

Comment: So what should I use ? pls help

Comment: Can u pls specify the exact update statement I should use for this ?

Comment: I think we can not use SET command and pass XML parameters over here

Comment: I tried this:    update CONNECTION_ACCOUNTS set SERVICE_SPECIFIC_DATA_V= ( xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<connection-specific>
  <connection value="0">
    <chargingGroupDetails>
      <groupInfo discountPercentage="10000000" classType="1" groupId="1001"/>
    </chargingGroupDetails>
  </connection>
</connection-specific')) where ACCOUNT_ID_N=1462;  it says  SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected BLOB got -
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Comment: UPDATE CONNECTION_ACCOUNTS set SERVICE_SPECIFIC_DATA_V= (RAWTOHEX (UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <connection-specific> <connection value="0"> <chargingGroupDetails> <groupInfo discountPercentage="10000000" classType="1" groupId="1001"/> </chargingGroupDetails> </connection> </connection-specific')))
   ACCOUNT_ID_N=1462;

Comment: Why do you insert XML into BLOB? Is it really required?
XML is a text data, so usually it should be stored as CLOB.

Comment: yes it is required actually for my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your statement to:

```
insert into connection_accounts
   (account_id
   ,service_specific_data_v)
values
   (1462
   , '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<connection-specific>
  <connection value="0">
    <chargingGroupDetails>
      <groupInfo discountPercentage="10000000" classType="1" groupId="1001"/>
    </chargingGroupDetails>
  </connection>
</connection-specific')
```

Or if there is already a record for that specific account_id to:

```
update connection_accounts
   set service_specific_data_v = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <connection-specific>
      <connection value="0">
        <chargingGroupDetails>
          <groupInfo discountPercentage="10000000" classType="1" groupId="1001"/>
        </chargingGroupDetails>
      </connection>
    </connection-specific'
 where account_id = 1462;
```